# Converting vector to indexed map in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

Let's say I have the following vector of maps:

```
[{:name "Jack" :age 5}
{:name "Joe" :age 15}
{:name "Mare" :age 34}
{:name "William" :age 64}
{:name "Adolf" :age 34}]
```

I want to convert this to an indexed map, like:

```
{1 {:name "Jack" :age 5}
 2 {:name "Joe" :age 15}
 3 {:name "Mare" :age 34}
 4 {:name "William" :age 64}
 5 {:name "Adolf" :age 34}}
```

And at some point, when I have modified the indexed map, I want to convert it back to vector of maps.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipmap` combines a series of keys and values, so you could do:

```
(zipmap (iterate inc 1) data-vector)
```

(with `data-vector` being your vector of maps)

The reverse would basically be sorting by key, then taking all values, which can be written exactly like that:

```
(->> data-map
     (sort-by key)
     (map val))
```

Comment: zipmaps makes sense and solves the first conversion, thanks! However, the reverse operation, mentioned by guillaume ERETEO, was more easy to understand for me: (vec (vals your-indexed-map)).

Comment: Which solution to use depends on whether you want to have the maps in the order given by the keys. `(vec (vals ...))` will potentially not maintain it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `map-indexed` in order to associate each map to its index and then reduce it into an hashmap:
`(reduce into {} (map-indexed #(assoc {} %1 %2) test))`

If you want to go back to your first structure:
`(vec (vals your-indexed-map))`